# Data type in php for both decimal and character values

Tags: php

Data type in php (that I should set for a column in phpmyadmin) for entering both character and decimal numbers. Ex. 0.09 or n.a. or 100 (1) all such things can be feed in to the column.

Comment: Have you tried a `VARCHAR`? This will hold a string allowing characters and decimals/numbers etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

A `VARCHAR` type can be used. This will store a string allowing your characters or decimals. Be sure to set an appropriate length - not too short or the data will be truncated.

If you find yourself storing lots of different types of data in a single field, then it may suggest you could use a better table/db design.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally store that data in two different fields:

one INT for whole numbers

and one DEC(m,n) for decimal numbers * m is number of all digits and n is number of digits behind the decimal separator.

For example: DEC(5,2) data for this would be 123.45

If you need it to be in one field use VARCHAR but this is not my recommend, since it is not good to store integers in varchar type field.

Answer (score 0):

Though a `varchar` is not recommended, but if you are using a `varchar` make sure you typecast the variable in your code while fetching.